# Disallow multitasking in MS Project

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, ms-project-2013

I have a worker assigned. He can only work half days (3.5 hours here).

After leveling for over-allocations, project wants him to work 1.75 hours on 2 tasks instead of 3.5 hours on one until completion and then 3.5 on the other until it's complete. He's a software developer, and not someone who should be multitasking.

I know I can force it to schedule one at a time if I add fake dependencies, but I was wondering if there was a better way to get project to stop assigning work in a multitasking fashion.

I'm using MS Project 2013.

Answer (score 2):

The resource leveling command will not change assignment units on tasks. So the only way for a resource to be working 1.75 hours on two tasks simultaneously would be if the resource is not assigned at his/her max units to all tasks.  If you want the resource to 'single task' their way through work - never assign at below max units and then use the resource leveling command to spread the tasks out.

For example - in the picture below, the resource's max units are 50%.  No links between tasks.  After resource leveling:

[image]

In the picture below, the resource's max units are 50% but s/he is assigned at below max on several tasks.  When leveling Project allows the 'multi-tasking' to occur because during the times of task overlap, the resource is not assigned to his/her max.

[image]

Comment: Okay so they're not scheduling in parallel, but now it tells me he's over-allocated and it's actually under-allocating him. It's putting him on one task for 1.75 hrs instead of 1 task for 3.5 hrs. It's like it doesn't want to allocate him at his max.

Comment: Again, the resource leveling command will not change assignment units.  Project doesn't allocate resources - you do.  The resource leveling command is NOT a resource optimization tool.  It's sole job is to resolve over allocations by delaying or splitting tasks.  If you are setting your leveling settings as less than day-by-day it is likely you will still see overallocations that most of us would ignore.